# Customer pair buying pattern 3 or more same product count

Tags: sql

I am trying to find customer pairs who have bought 3 or more of the same products at the same time and count how many times they have done that.

for example: highlighted would count as 1 for pair customer pair 1-2:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I have to use self-join but I don't know how to count them.

Database: 
[image: tables]

This is what I'm looking for: 
[image: result]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: You say "on the same date", but your table has two date columns.  Confusing.

Comment: `date_a` and `date_b` are the same `order_date` in the database. I put it next to each other in the image to show that you should only count it if the dates are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.  You seem to want customers who have ordered the same three products on the same day.  The following gets all combinations of three projects per date and then compares them to get the pairs you are looking for:

```
with o3 as (
     select o1.customer_id, o1.order_date,
            o1.product_id as product_id_1,
            o2.product_id as product_id_2,
            o3.product_id as product_id_3
     from orders o1 join
          orders o2
          on o1.order_date = o2.order_date and
             o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id and
             o1.product_id < o2.product_id join
          orders o3
          on o2.order_date = o3.order_date and
             o2.customer_id = o3.customer_id and
             o2.product_id < o3.product_id
    )
select o3.customer_id, o3_2.*
from o3 join
     o3 o3_2
     on o3_2.order_date = o3.order_date and
        o3_2.product_id_1 = o3.product_id_1 and
        o3_2.product_id_2 = o3.product_id_2 and
        o3_2.product_id_3 = o3.product_id_3 and
        o3_2.customer_id > o3.custer_id;
```